# Is there a way of fixing a maximum value for an element in an array?

Tags: ruby

```
list = [5, 10, 20, 40, 50, 42, 35, 26, 18]
```

So in this example, I don't want an element to exceed the value 40 and if it does, I want the element to have a value of 40, e.g. the element with the value 50 will become 40.

Comment: The answer is "yes". Were it "no", Ruby would reside in the dead-language dumpster and we wouldn't be talking about it. Your question should be, "How do I..."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list.map! { |i| i > 40 ? 40 : i }
 => [5, 10, 20, 40, 40, 40, 35, 26, 18]
```

`map` method permits you to apply a transformation to all the elements of your collection so I think fits perfectly in this case.

Or, if you are populating your array one element at a time, you could insert the real value just if it's 40 or less, 40 otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

If `40` is the max, you need the [`min`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-min) from 40 and the element ;)

```
list = [5, 10, 20, 40, 50, 42, 35, 26, 18]
list.map{ |v| [40, v].min }
# => [5, 10, 20, 40, 40, 40, 35, 26, 18]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Ruby 2.4 or newer, you can make use of [Comparable#clamp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Comparable.html#method-i-clamp):

```
list.map { |n| n.clamp(0, 40) }
# => [5, 10, 20, 40, 40, 40, 35, 26, 18]
```

Note that this will also fix the minimum value to `0`. This may or may not be useful in your case, and only applies if all items are expected to be non-negative numbers.

Comment: That's a potentially useful comment, but there is not enough information to say if this is the "wrong" method. It offers more robustness in cases where the numbers are implicitly assumed to be non-negative. This assumption is explicated in the answer.

Comment: There's nothing in the question that seems to indicate that negative numbers should be replaced by 0. Also, why should this method be more robust than `min`?

Comment: You could write `[5, 10, 20, 40, -5000, 42, 35, 26, 18].map { |n| n.clamp(-Float::INFINITY, 40) } #=> [5, 10, 20, 40, -5000, 40, 35, 26, 18]` but I agree with @Eric that here it doesn't offer any advantage over the well-worn method `min`.  Good to know about another method with a great name, however. It will take its place alongside `squeeze`, `chomp`, `chop`,  `scrub`, `lazy`, `chunk`, `dig` and others, plus, of course, the operator `splat`.

Comment: @EricDuminil: All numbers in the example are non-negative, which definitely could be incidental, but that doesn't matter, because the assumption, again, is explicated in the *answer*. It is clearly more robust *under that assumption*.

Comment: It is not useless. I suggest reading up on the robustness principle. I'm going to ignore any more mentions about the assumption, since it is very clearly stated.

Comment: @EricDuminil: I understand. My first approach would also be your answer. I added this one for others to find (hoping that they will be able choose the one that fits their case.) I apologize for the snarky replies.